# how to resolve "the device is not compatible in this application"? when application install by google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have made Qr code based application and i upload application on google play, but when i install application in "Sony Z ultra" phone then google play says "The device is not compatible in this application" why? i have proper entry in manifest of application.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

menifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

        <application
            android:name=".HashKeyGenerate.Key"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".QRCodeScanClass.QRcodeScanner"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".QRCodeGenerateClass.QRCode_Generator"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".FavouriteActivity"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".QRCodeSaveShareBrowseActivity"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".BrowseActivity"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

            <activity
                android:name=".ShareTextActivity"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".ShareActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges=
                    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/app_id"/>
            <provider
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider229614757390150"
                android:exported="true" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                android:value="b7ac97c139b35db9b4557ea33ac61de07ed74d87" />

        </application>
```

I have given package name in manifest.

Is it problem by android developer or google play?

Thanking You

Comment: Can you post your complete manifest ?

Comment: @Passiondroid i have edit my question, Please see this.

Comment: Is this happening only on a **Sony Z ultra**? Have you to a different phone? Another phone with the same model?

Comment: **android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"**

will allways be overriden by value in gradle file. to remove ambiguity you need to delete this from androidMenifest file.

Comment: @sept :- yes , this problem occur in Sony Z ultra. i have not another Sony phone.

Comment: @AmitVaghela are you sure about it ? is it ambiguity problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have added three uses-feature tag

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Check that all three features are available on your target device and if not available then mark that feature as android:required="false"

Comment: :- i am not understand what are you saying brother. are saying that i do android:required = "true"?

Comment: @MayankSugandhi Use <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>. It will work as Sony Z ultra do not have flash. Also accept this as answer it helped you.

Comment: :- ok i will try and let you know. :)

Comment: :- it it right  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/> this permission?

Comment: @MayankSugandhi - <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>   You have to add required = 'false" in this.

Comment: :- yes brother i have done this please check  . is it right?
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

Comment: This is right : <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

Comment: can i entry this permission :- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>  or it is wrong. i want to ask you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106678/discussion-between-passiondroid-and-mayank-sugandhi).